# Debezium source to Postgres sink DB- JDBC Sink connector issue

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Getting below error with JDBC sync connector.

```
 ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=12sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Cannot ALTER TABLE "new1501"."test"."patient3" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot ALTER TABLE "new1501"."test"."patient3" to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source:STRUCT}, name='source', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.amendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:153)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:75)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:123)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:601)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

My source connector config:

```
{
    "name": "150-connector-2",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "database.hostname": "**",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "***",
        "database.dbname": "kafka-source-test",
        "database.server.name": "new1501",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "snapshot.mode": "always"
    }
}
```

My sink connector config:

```
{
    "name": "12sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "new1501.test.patient3",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/db",         
        "connection.user":"postgres",
    "connection.password":"**",        
        "auto-evolve":"true" ,
        "auto-create":"true" ,           
        "insert.mode": "insert",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
        "pk.fields": "home_id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true" 
 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below article is similar to your use case.
https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/

In summary, in the JDBC Sink Connector configuration, you would need to use a "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState" SMT (single message transformation), so that the JDBC Sink Connector can readily consume the content in the Kafka topic message.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your sink table cannot add a "source" field, because there's no default schema value for it (nor should there be a default).

If you consume the source topic, you'll notice it likely doesn't match the columns of your database exactly (you'll want to create the table ahead of time). This is because you need to first extract the `after` state using a transform. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html

Comment: I have tried to create the tables first also. But same issue.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said you needed a transform to extract the after state and to look at the messages with a consumer to see what I mean